# Can I use the computer power on a different machine for docker?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I use docker locally for development. I run a few containers for Redis, Postgres, the frontend compilation and backend compilation. The frontend and backend map files from my local machine to the docker containers where a process runs that auto compiles. Then I can access the backend server and frontend webserver from services in the docker container hosting them.

My backend can be very resource-intensive as I'm developing a task that processes a large amount of time-series data. It can take about 5-10 mins on my machine. I'm using a 15-inch Macbook pro as my local machine and running docker and my development setup is really pushing my machine to the limits. I'm considering running docker on another Linux PC I have and connecting to it from my MacBook pro.

I use CircleCI quite a bit and they have some setup with docker where the CI containers you run don't actually run docker themselves but are networked out to a separate dedicated machine. The only issue is mapping volumes don't work too great.

**How can I set this up in docker so that I can run docker commands locally that run on a separate machine?**

**Any ideas how I can map the directories to the other machine?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH to run commands on another machine:

```
ssh user@server docker run hello-world
```

I would recommend against mapping volumes, as that doesn't work well. Instead, I'd simply copy the data you needed to the server.

```
scp -r directory-to-copy/* user@server:/destination-to-copy-into
```

Comment: Here is a blog about connecting to remote docker daemon over ssh - https://sujaypillai.dev/2019/01/2019-01-22-docker-tip/